# randomize portion of an PHP object array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, random

I want to randomise part of an object array. Like I have an array of 10 elements and I want to sort first 5 entries in random order, where other/last 5 entries will be exactly same. Is there any easy/efficient way to do this is PHP? Thanks.

Comment: Show us your tried code of awesomeness

Comment: Sorry, not array_shuffle, `shuffle`

Comment: There is not a single function. However, you can combine a few of the PHP array functions. [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) and [`shuffle`](http://php.net/shuffle).

```
$array = array_pad(array(), 10, ""); // 10 elements

$first = array_slice($array, 0, 5);
shuffle($first); // can't shuffle inline so do it like this
$array = array_merge($first, array_slice($array, 5, 5))
```

Comment: Your usage of `array_rand()` is incorrect. You mean, `shuffle()` or pass the second parameter.

Comment: I thought `array_rand` did what `shuffle` does. PHP function naming is .. interesting. `array_rand`, even with the second parameter, doesn't return values, it always returns keys.

Comment: By the way `array_rand` also can be used. I think your previous version is workable too

Comment: No, because it returns keys. You can probably find a way to use it (`array_flip`?), but this works and I'm happy with this.

Comment: @u_mulder, `shuffle()` is the appropriate function.

Answer (score 1):

You can split, then shuffle one, then combine them.

```
$myArr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
$randArr = array_slice($myArr, 0, 3);
shuffle($randArr);
$staticArr = array_slice($myArr, 3);

$finalArr = array_merge($randArr, $staticArr);
```

Comment: Note that shuffle does not return the array - like sort() it takes the variable by reference, then returns true on success or false on failure.